# convert arry list key to call array and repace value

Tags: php

i want map list array to call array and replace value

```
$data=[
'w'=>[
    1=>[
      r=>[
        2=>[
           j=>10
          ]
       ]
    ],
    2=>[
      r=>[
        2=>[
           j=>10
          ]
       ]
    ]


]
]


$map=['w',1,'r',2,'j'];
```

convert to;

```
$data['w'][1]['r'][2][j]+=200;
```

how to make some function to read $map end run like ?

```
$data['w'][1]['r'][2][j]+=200;
```

return

```
$data=[
    'w'=>[
        1=>[
          r=>[
            2=>[
               j=>210
              ]
           ]
        ],
        2=>[
          r=>[
            2=>[
               j=>10
              ]
           ]
        ]


    ]
    ]
```

im stuck to make function to read $map to dynamicaly
like

$map=['g','y'];

program will call map like $data['g']['y'];

Comment: What's your desired output? How it should look like?

Comment: i want return like that return data
i try ise $data_return['...']['...'] but it just staticaly
how to create fucntion  to handle dynamic [ ...][' ...'] *n

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need something like this:

```
function getVal(array $data, array $map) {

    $result = $data;

    foreach ($map as $key) {
        $result = $result[$key];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
$data = [
    'w' => [
        1 => [
            'r' => [
                2 => [
                    'j' => 10
                ]
            ]
        ],
        2 => [
            'r' => [
                2 => [
                    'j' => 10
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$map=['w',1,'r',2,'j'];

echo getVal($data, $map);
```

If you want to mutate the data, returned by the function, you can use references.

EDIT:

This function set a desired value:

```
function setVal(array &$data, array $map, int $value) {

    $fullName = '';
    foreach ($map as $key) {
        $fullName .= "['$key']";
    }

    eval('$data' . $fullName . " = $value;");
}
```

Comment: sory it like just get value from nested array object.
i want to replace some value by map end return fully object but value has change change

Comment: Generally `eval()` should be avoided as much as possible.